# merge two github branches

Tags: git, github, github-pages

So was starting with GitHub and created a repo with same name as the folder (i.e. resume) on my desktop. Now it created a default branch of name **main**.

Using a GitHub document (*https://gist.github.com/mindplace/b4b094157d7a3be6afd2c96370d39fad*), I pushed my code to the same repository in GitHub.

Now there are two branches in my GitHub repo (**main** and **master**).I tried to merge the two using Pull Request, but GitHub said that *There is nothing to compare in the two branches*.

I want to have **master** as my only branch. What can I do? Plz Help.

Here's the link to the repo *https://github.com/Ankit29Git/resume.git*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete the main branch from the remote.

```
git push origin --delete main
```

for brief you can follow this https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-delete-a-git-branch-both-locally-and-remotely/

Comment: Hi Pulak. This is not working.     `$ git push origin --delete main
To https://github.com/Ankit29Git/resume.git
 ! [remote rejected] main (refusing to delete the current branch: refs/heads/main)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/Ankit29Git/resume.git'`

Comment: First push master, then go to github and configure the "default branch" for your repository to be master, then afterwards you can delete it. You can change this from the branches overview page, at `https://github.com/USERNAME/REPONAME/branches`

Comment: Thanks Lasse and Pulak

Comment: yeah you have to make master as a default branch before deleting the main branch.